# Can you start Crystal Reports 10 in read only mode so users can't create or change a report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm in an environment where I have created reports in CrystalReports 10 and only want my users to view the report from an external application.  The application is already set up to open the report with crystal, but I don't want my users to be able create or change the report.  I can't seem to find a command line option to do this.  Is there a runtime only version of Crystal?

Comment: "open the report with crystal" ...What do you mean by this? Are you loading the report into a viewer or are you launching the external crystal designer?

Answer (score 3):

embed crviewer and craxdrt components in your app (delivered with CR developer's edition, free to distribute) so that you'll be able to view reports without modifying them. Basic manipulations (zoom, search, export to pdf, display/hide details or groups) can still be done.

If you must launch this viewer from a command line, I'd advise you to embed it in an office document/file and manage it through VBA. You could for example launch the runtime version of Access (free to distribute) that will contain one generic form for Crystal Reports display.

Answer (score 2):

There are Crystal Reports viewer components which you can use in your projects. They are coming with the Crystal Reports Developer editions and you can use them in almost every programming language. There you can define the report as view only if you want.

Comment: Unfortunatly, we have to use an outside vendor's application for this and it only provides for command line links to an outside report genereator, so I am unable to add any components to the app.

Comment: As an alternative, there is a Crystal Report Viewer available here: http://www.businessobjects.com/forms/crystalreports/viewer/
But if you could control which application is started to open the report, you could write your own viewer using the crystal components.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [SAP.com](http://www.sap.com) and search for "Crystal Reports Viewer". It may or may not do what you want.

Also take a look at "Crystal Reports Server". CRS XI is a nice reporting portal with many useful server-side features. Schedule reports to run and auto-publish. Generate PDF or Excel output. Limit access to reports (or groups of reports) by specific users, etc. But for your application you can use HTTP access within your application to the published results. This is a good solution for example when you have a large number of users viewing the same reports.

Answer (score 0):

What about marking the file as read-only?  If the viewer opiton isn't open to you.